# my python code doesn't get executed. No error, no process finished text just blank. Other codes works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = ["5", "-", "2", "+", "1"]
int_list = []
while len(list1) > 0:
    if len(int_list) < 1:
        int_list.append(int(list1[0]))
        list1.pop(0)
    int_list.append(0)
    int_list.append(int(list1[1]))
    int_list.pop(0)
    int_list.pop(0)
print(int_list)
```

I'm trying to make calculator. But this code doesn't execute.  Like no errors no texts just blank. Anyone knows why this happening?

Comment: I suspect that your loop is just not terminating. It isn't clear to me how this code is meant to implement a calculator, but in any case, perhaps you should put some printing inside it to see if your list contains the values you expect.  That may help you understand what you're doing wrong that's stopping the loop from terminating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors (just mentioned in earlier post), so I would not repeat.

It seems that you are starting to implement some *stack* data structure to do some math evaluation.  Great!  Here is some suggestions and code snippet for you to start.

First, try to use meaningful but succinct variable names. Secondly, write some *pseudo code* in paper and *flowchart*, then finally implement it.  The chance of success at first time is much much better..

```
L = ["5", "-", "2", "+", "1"]
eval_lst = list()

for i, x in enumerate(L):
    try:
        eval_lst.append(int(x))
        
    except ValueError:
        eval_lst.append(x)
```

Comment: god damn bro thats so smart

Comment: Try this great visual platform next time to see program running step-by-step:  https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

The condition `len(list1) > 0` will always be `True` cause you are not removing any item from `list1`.

To do this you need to replace

`list1.pop(0)` -> `del list1[0]` and

`int_list.pop(0)` -> `del int_list[0]`

You have to use `del` to remove the item at a specific index

Comment: You have correctly identified the reason why the loop does not end, but the explanation is wrong.

Comment: Any tips to improve the answer?

Comment: Remove the wrong parts about how `pop` works. It uses an index, not a value.

Comment: thanks bro but why pop doesn't work?